# Rotate raster R

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to to a raster object that has x coordinates (longitude) from 0 to 360, to standard coordinates between -180 and 180 degrees.

I have a matrix where the longitude range is (0,360) and the latitude range is (-90,90) and has a resolution of 0.75 so that its dimensions are

```
dim(x)
[1] 480 241
```

Then I try

```
r <- rotate(x)
```

And I get this error

```
Error in rotate(x) : object "phy" is not of class "phylo"
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. I also don't understand how this operation is a rotation. It seems to be only a shift (transformation of coordinates).

Comment: Yes @Roland it is a shift but the package is called rotate

Comment: So, you are talking about the raster package?

Comment: @Roland yes http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/rotate

Comment: I repeat: Provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `raster::rotate(x)`.  You happen to have loaded the `ape` package *after* you loaded the `raster` package; both packages contain `rotate` functions.  (Another alternative would be to `detach("package:ape")` and try again.)

If you type `find("rotate")` R will tell you where it's finding the function; the first element of the vector is the one it chooses by default.

When you loaded `ape` you should have gotten the following message:

```
Attaching package: ‘ape’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:raster’:
    rotate, zoom
```